# In a list of tagged elements, how do I efficiently find tagged elements whose tags include all the tags that I specify?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, filtering, keyword

I have a number of tagged objects (called TagObj):

```
class TagObj { 
    name: string;
    tags: string[];
}
```

I want to implement a fast function to return all objects which contain the tags I specify

```
getTagObjsMatching(objs: TagObj[], tagsFilters: string[]): TagObj[] {
    // return all elements of objs which contain all specified filter tags
}
```

```
var objsExample: TagObj[] = [
    { name: "apple", tags: ["round", "red", "sweet"] },
    { name: "banana", tags: ["long", "yellow", "sweet"] },
    { name: "sea urchin", tags: ["round", "spiked", "salty", "savory"] },
    { name: "watermelon", tags: ["oblong", "red", "sweet"] },
];
getTagObjsMatching(objsExample, ["sweet", "red"]); 
// returns:
// [{ name: "apple", tags: ["round", "red", "sweet"] }, { name: "watermelon", tags: ["oblong", "red", "sweet"] }]
```

I want to be able to store my TagObjs in memory, allowing for efficient addition and deletion of TagObj elements. I can assume there are no 2 TagObjs sharing the same name.
Intermediate data structures can be constructed for making getTagObjsMatching() more performant.
My current solution uses a 2-way dictionary mapping:

```
dictionary1 from name to TagObj (used for retrieval and deletion)
dictionary2 from tag to all a set containing TagObjs (for getTagObjsMatching())
  Initialize the result to all TagObjs.
  For each tag of tagsFilters:
    delete from the result all elements that do not contain the tag (use dictionary2 for lookup)
  return the filtered result.
```

I'm looking for a solution which runs better than O(n^2).